# request node.js module can't send a simple POST

Tags: node.js, http, post

I send it like so :

```
var url     = "http://localhost:9001/v1/sanger/auth/facebook/callback",
    options = {body: JSON.stringify(params), 'Content-type': 'application/json'};

    request.post(url, options, function (error, response, body) {
      ... callbacks ... 
    });
```

I am not getting the params in the route (tried `body`, `params` and `query`)

When I use postman (http://cl.ly/image/473e2m173M2v) I get it in the `req.body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do this (I'm assuming you've initialized your `params` variable somewhere else):

```
request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: "http://localhost:9001/v1/sanger/auth/facebook/callback",
  method: 'POST',
  body: params,
  json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  ... callbacks ... 
});
```

You're not able to get the `body` because when you call `JSON.stringify(params)`, you're converting `params` to a string and you don't have a `json` object anymore. If you send the information as `plain/text` but tell the `request` that you want `json`, your express app cannot verify the `content-type`, as could check with:

```
request.get('Content-Type'); // returns undefined
```

Since you want a `json` object, you shouldn't do this. Just pass the `json` object, like in the example above.

Then, in your route code, you can do both `req.body` or `req.param('a_param')` (for a especific key of your `json`) to get those values.